# Changing direction infinitely

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make the enemy change direction when he touches the player, but when he touches it, it starts changing the direction without stopping, something like this gif:

[Image (Epilepsy warning)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PvOZ.gif)

my code:

```
private int directionValue = 1;
public Vector2 speed = new Vector2((3/2), 0);
public Vector2 direction = new Vector2(-1, 0);
private Vector2 movement;

void Update()
{
    movement = new Vector2(
        speed.x * direction.x * directionValue,
        speed.y * direction.y);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rigidbody2D.velocity = movement;
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    foreach (string i in changeDir) {
        if (coll.gameObject.name == i) {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1 * this.gameObject.transform.localScale.x, this.gameObject.transform.localScale.y, 1);
            directionValue *= -1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a problem if it touches for more than a frame. It moves away for a frame, then back towards the played for a frame, so youre back to square one. And voila infinite loop. You could try a delay before changing direction again.

Comment: I'm new to c#, what function should I use to make a delay?

Comment: Shouldn't there be an epilepsy warning in this post? :)

Comment: sorry hahaha I removed it now

Comment: @SergioToledoPiza Delay could be as simple keeping track of which frame/time you changed direction, and waiting at least x frame/ms before changing again.

Comment: +1 Although I was unconstructively hypnotized by the image. I agree with the `epilepsy warning`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Borgleader mentioned the problem is that the touch is lasting more than a frame and then you are setting the direction back and forth. You can either find out which direction is away from the player and set the direction based on that on every time OnCollisionEnter2D is called.

```
    if(gameObject.transform.position.x > coll.gameObject.transform.position.x)
    {
        directionValue = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        directionValue = -1;
    }
```

Or you can use a timer

```
public  float hitWait = 0.1f;
private float lastHitTime = 0.0;

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    foreach (string i in changeDir) {
        if (coll.gameObject.name == i) {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1 * this.gameObject.transform.localScale.x, this.gameObject.transform.localScale.y, 1);
            float timeNow = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
            if(timeNow > lastHitTime + hitWait){
                lastHitTime = timeNow;
                directionValue *= -1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```